# Silverstripe comment module is not working

Tags: module, comments, silverstripe

i have installed silverstripe comment module but the comment form on page is not appearing also as they said in installation.md

> Out of the box the module adds commenting support to all pages on your site. This functionality can be turned on and off on a per page basis in the CMS under the `Behaviour` tab for a given page. Once the `Allow Comments` checkbox is ticked, republish and view the webpage.

but  the `Allow Comments` checkbox is not appearing too
here's  my composer.json :-

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe/reports": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe/siteconfig": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "3.1.*",
        "assertchris/hash-compat": "^1.0",
        "colymba/gridfield-bulk-editing-tools": "^2.1",
        "silverstripe/comments": "^2.0",
        "silverstripe/lumberjack": "^1.1",
        "silverstripe/tagfield": "^1.2",
        "silverstripe/blog": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/PHPUnit": "~3.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Assuming you have rebuilt the database? /dev/build?flush

Comment: Did you use ?flush=1 in the browser? This clears your frontend cache

Comment: yes, i did also I fixed the problem. the problem was I need to add the following to your config.yml file: `SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - CommentsExtension
comments:
    require_login: true` then `dev/build?flush=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add

```
SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - CommentsExtension
  comments:
    require_login: true
```

in */mysite/config.yml*

Then simply "/dev/build?flush=1"

Comment: Don't forget to add a spamprotection, I've added a HoneyPot (https://packagist.org/packages/studiobonito/silverstripe-spamprotection-honeypot) field to the comments form that helped a lot. http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/simple-spam-protection-for-comments/ (disclaimer: my blog)